# jquery reveal modal popup alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After opening popup, want to disable the background in jquery reveal modal. Please look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nB5N/14/). In this fiddle it is working, but it has taking the whole screen. I want to set it as inside the particular div.

```js
$(function () {

    $(document).foundation();

    $('ul.f-dropdown li a').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('Dropdown clicked', event.target);
        $('.reveal-modal').foundation('dropdown', 'closeall');
    });

});
```

```css
.generation .reveal-modal {
    background-color: red;
}
.generation{
  width:700px;
  height:400px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Wonky Modal</a>

<div class='generation'>
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
         <h2>Wonky Dropdown Dialog</h2>
 <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>

        <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a href="#">This is a link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">This is another</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another</a>

            </li>
        </ul> <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>

    </div>
</div><!-- / .generation -->
<hr/>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myWorkingModal">Click Me For A Working Modal</a>

<div id="myWorkingModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
     <h2>Working Dropdown Dialog</h2>

<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>

    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
        <li><a href="#">This is a link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">This is another</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Yet another</a>

        </li>
    </ul> <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>

</div>
```

Please check this fiddle and help me for do this.

Comment: Can you give us a working modal?

Comment: What background are you reffering to?!

Comment: I want rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) this background color and that popup also should open inside the main container div only. No need to take the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a modal dialog is the appropriate element to use in this situation. A modal dialog is normally used to grab the user's attention and have them perform a global action, such as a confirmation message for deleting something. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your modal, but I would suggest going for more of a simple show/hide section. This way, it can be placed within the context of your content block. Foundation's modals are always going to be positioned relative to the viewport, not to a specific container.

Check out this article on how modals and overlays are best used: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/overuse-of-overlays/